# Find Mongoose Document and then Sort Randomly with Different Tiers?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I currently have a .find() associated with documents in a collection, and it's currently sorting the document based on their "status" and sorting them by their most recent. Is it possible to sort them by the status first, and then randomly sort those within their respective tiers?

For instance if I have users that are three tiers: Tier 1, Tier 2, and Tier 3. Currently, it's sorting by Tier 1's (most recently), then Tier 2's (most recently), then Tier 3's (most recently). I'd like it to instead sort like: Tier 1's (random), Tier 2's (random), Tier 3's (random). But still display the results like so: Tier 1, Tier 2, then Tier 3. Is this possible?

```
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {

    const errors = {};

    Users.find().sort({tierStatus: -1, tierStatus: -1, tierStatus: -1})
        .then(users => {
            if (!users) {
                errors.nousers = 'There are no users';
                return res.status(404).json(errors);
            }
            res.json(users);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({
            nousers: 'There are no users'
        }));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no way to generate a random value in MongoDB thus you cannot sort "randomly". The only operator you can consider is [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) which picks random documents but you cannot use it along with `sort()` or `$sort`

The only solution is to sort by deterministic field and then shuffle in your application logic.

Comment: Is it possible for me to use a function that will generate a random number and loop through all the returned values in the original find? Like instead of where I have tierStatus: -1 for the sort, is it possible to add a callback function there?

Comment: @Buckyx55 no, you can only use built-in operators https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

you can use $sample sort operator in mongoose aggregation
for example I'd like select 6 random blogs:

```
const randomBlogs = await blogs.aggregate([
   { $sample: { size: 6 } },
]);
```